# How should I design this code (parallel class hierarchies)?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a set of apps that all need to synchronize with a webservice:

1. download some XML from a webservice.
2. parse that XML.
3. then update the database to match the parsed XML.

I'd like to keep as much of the relevant code as possible in a common library to avoid duplication, and I'd like to have the different apps all slot their parsing and updating code into a fairly simple common framework.

So there's a common sync() method:

```
public void sync(URI updateUrl, XMLParser parser, Updater animalUpdater) {
    String raw = getXML();
    List<ParsedAnimal> parsed = parser.parse(raw);
    // try:
    // begin transaction
    for (ParsedAnimal pi : parsed) {
        animalUpdater.updateItem(pi);
    }
    // commit transaction
    // catch: rollback transaction, rethrow
    // finally: close database connection
}
```

The parser returns either a ParsedCat, or ParsedDog, or whatever, all of which inherit from a common ParsedAnimal class:

```
public abstract class ParsedAnimal {...}
public class ParsedCat extends ParsedAnimal {...}
public class ParsedDog extends ParsedAnimal {...}
```

Then I have an Updater which needs to take the parsed item and inject the contents into the database:

```
public abstract class Updater {
    public abstract void updateItem(ParsedAnimal parsed);
}
public class CatUpdater extends Updater {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(ParsedCat parsed) {}
}
public class DogUpdater extends Updater {...}
```

This doesn't work — the contract for Updater specifies that updateItem() accepts a ParsedAnimal, and CatUpdater and DogUpdater both break that contract by only accepting a specific type of animal.

What I have is a parallel class hierarchy — ParsedX matches up one to one with XUpdater. The [Code Smells](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html) page on Coding Horror suggests merging the two class hierarchies into a single hierarchy, but I feel like the "thing being worked on" and the "thing doing the working" are different enough that they should be separate classes.

Is there a neat way of structuring this, or some design pattern that would come in handy?

Comment: Yes, use generics: `public abstract class Updater<T extends ParsedAnimal> {` and `public class CatUpdate extends Updater<ParsedCat> {`.  And in Updater: `public abstract void updateItem(T parsed);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics can come in handy for your issue with the `Updater` contract:

```
public abstract class Updater<T extends ParsedAnimal> {
    public abstract void updateItem(T parsed);
}
public class CatUpdater extends Updater<ParsedCat> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(ParsedCat parsed) {}
}
public class DogUpdater extends Updater<ParsedDog> {...}
```

However, your `sync` method has an `Updater` as a param that it tries to use for all parsed items.  This won't work.  If you're going to have a separate `Updater` per parsed type, you'll need to get instantiate the updater based on which parse result your have.  This can be handled by some form of "Factory".  For a start, you might want to look at using the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer - I didn't realise that I could "hardcode" generics like that by specifying the generic type in the extends.

Comment: @Don Roby: I have a clarification here. How would you call this Updater method? I mean, can you update your post with the caller method of Updater which iterates through each item in parsed animal list and call this update method using generics.

Comment: @Rockstart: That was basically the point of my notes about the sync method.  You need something that will create an appropriate `Updater` for each thing parsed.  There are some choices in how you do this.  I might (later today) try to come up with a bit of sample code and add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
updateItem(ParsedAnimal parsed){
    if (parsed instanceof ParsedCat) {
        ... 
    } else if (parsed instanceof ParsedDog) {
        ... 
    } 
}
```